# Deserialize XML to Object - null value from attrubutes

Tags: c#, xml

When i try load xml configuration file to object, all xml elements was deserialized, but "xml attrubutes" load as null.

I have xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<CAS_POLSKA>

 <Komunikacja>
   <Typ>RS232</Typ>
   <Port>6</Port>
   <BaudRate>115200</BaudRate>
   <Interval>5000</Interval>
   <Retry>3</Retry>
   <TYPWAGI>POS</TYPWAGI>
   <!-- model type of scale (CL5000, LP16, POSCALE, etc...). --> 
   <RODZAJWAGI>POSCALE</RODZAJWAGI>
   <PASEKPOSTEPU>1</PASEKPOSTEPU>
   <DEBUGMESS>1</DEBUGMESS>
   <AKCJA>WYSYLKA</AKCJA>
   <TYPDANYCH>PLU</TYPDANYCH>
</Komunikacja>

<DEFAULT DEPARTMENT="1" PLUTYPE="1" />

 <Dane>
   <!-- W polu Grupa definiujemy bitowo NW, FIX i BAR -->  

  <RECORD PLU="1" NAZWA01="AccesPoint LINKSYS WRT 54G" UNITPRICE="30378" ITEMCODE="1234"/>
   <RECORD PLU="2" NAZWA01="Access Point EDIMAX EW-7209" UNITPRICE="30500" ITEMCODE="222" GROUP="1"/>
   <RECORD PLU="3" NAZWA01="szynka" UNITPRICE="1000" ITEMCODE="3133" GROUP="3"/>
   <RECORD PLU="4" NAZWA01="szynka" UNITPRICE="2000" ITEMCODE="3134" GROUP="4"/>
   <RECORD PLU="5" NAZWA01="szynka" UNITPRICE="3000"  GROUP="7"/>
 </Dane>
</CAS_POLSKA>
```

And i try to read it to object:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(CAS_POLSKA));
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"plu_cas.xml");
            CAS_POLSKA CAS = new CAS_POLSKA();
            CAS = (CAS_POLSKA)reader.Deserialize(file);
        }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class CAS_POLSKA
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Komunikacja")]
        public Komunikacja komunikacja { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("Dane")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("RECORD", typeof(Record))]
        public Record[] record { get; set; }
    }


    [Serializable()]
    public class Komunikacja
    {
        //...
        //this code load correctly
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class Record
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("NR")]
        public int NR { get; set; }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("NAZWA")]
        public string NAZWA { get; set; }
    }
```

And it load CAS.rocord load 5 elements in array, but all atributes NR and NAZWA is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names in the [`[XmlAttribute(name)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes that appear in the `Record` class must correspond to the attribute names that appear in the XML. You currently have `NR` and `NAZWA`, but these do not appear in the XML.  Instead it includes the following attributes:

```
<RECORD 
    PLU="2" 
    NAZWA01="Access Point EDIMAX EW-7209" 
    UNITPRICE="30500" 
    ITEMCODE="222" 
    GROUP="1"/>
```

Thus your `Record` class needs to look like:

```
public class Record
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("PLU")]
    public int PLU { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("NAZWA01")]
    public string Nazwa01 { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("UNITPRICE")]
    public int UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("ITEMCODE")]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("GROUP")]
    public string Group { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your classes should be like this

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Komunikacja")]
    public class Komunikacja {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Typ")]
        public string Typ { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Port")]
        public string Port { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="BaudRate")]
        public string BaudRate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Interval")]
        public string Interval { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Retry")]
        public string Retry { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="TYPWAGI")]
        public string TYPWAGI { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="RODZAJWAGI")]
        public string RODZAJWAGI { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="PASEKPOSTEPU")]
        public string PASEKPOSTEPU { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="DEBUGMESS")]
        public string DEBUGMESS { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="AKCJA")]
        public string AKCJA { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="TYPDANYCH")]
        public string TYPDANYCH { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="DEFAULT")]
    public class DEFAULT {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="DEPARTMENT")]
        public string DEPARTMENT { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="PLUTYPE")]
        public string PLUTYPE { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="RECORD")]
    public class RECORD {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="PLU")]
        public string PLU { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="NAZWA01")]
        public string NAZWA01 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="UNITPRICE")]
        public string UNITPRICE { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="ITEMCODE")]
        public string ITEMCODE { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="GROUP")]
        public string GROUP { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Dane")]
    public class Dane {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="RECORD")]
        public List<RECORD> RECORD { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="CAS_POLSKA")]
    public class CAS_POLSKA {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Komunikacja")]
        public Komunikacja Komunikacja { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="DEFAULT")]
        public DEFAULT DEFAULT { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Dane")]
        public Dane Dane { get; set; }
    }
}
```